# Python: zfill with rsub padding zeroes

Tags: python, padding

I wrote a script to standardize a bunch of values pulled from a data bank using (mostly) r.sub. I am having a hard time incorporating zfill to pad the numerical values at 5 digits.

Input

```
FOO5864BAR654FOOBAR
```

Desired Output

```
FOO_05864-BAR-00654_FOOBAR
```

Using re.sub I have so far

```
FOO_5864-BAR-654_FOOBAR
```

One option was to do re.sub w/ capturing groups for each possible format [i.e. below], which works, but I don't think that's the correct way to do it.

```
(\d)         sub   0000\1
(\d\d)       sub   000\1
(\d\d\d)     sub   00\1
(\d\d\d\d)   sub   0\1
```

Comment: What's the problem with using zfill? I'm not sure why you're considering using regex when zfill exists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your inputs are all of the form letters-numbers-letters-numbers-letters (one or more of each), you just need to zero-fill the second and fourth groups from the match:

```
import re

s = 'FOO5864BAR654FOOBAR'
pattern = r'(\D+)(\d+)(\D+)(\d+)(\D+)'
m = re.match(pattern, s)
out = '{}_{:0>5}-{}-{:0>5}_{}'.format(*m.groups())
print(out)  # -> FOO_05864-BAR-00654_FOOBAR
```

You could also do this with `str.zfill(5)`, but the `str.format` method is just much cleaner.